# SQLAlchemy cannot find referenced table via foreignkey in many-to-many relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys, many-to-many, flask-sqlalchemy

I have already succeeded in adding one many-to-many relationship in my database. However, when trying to add another, I am met with:

`sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'user_shiftTemplate.template_id' could not find table 'shifttemplate' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'`

I have defined the association table before my two tables I am trying to create a relationship with:

```
user_shiftTemplate = db.Table('user_shiftTemplate',
db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
db.Column('template_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('shifttemplate.id'))
)
```

And here are my actual two tables I am trying to create the relationship for (again, defined AFTER the association table shown above)

```py
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    oauth_id = db.Column(db.String(512), nullable=False, unique=True, default='')
    ext_id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, unique=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(300), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(256), unique=True, nullable=False)
    phone = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    date_joined = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=getPacificTime)
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    meta = db.Column(db.JSON, nullable=False, default={})

    shifts = db.relationship('Shift', secondary=user_shift, backref='employees') 
    #^^^^ This is the other many-to-many relationship which actually works ^^^^
    shiftTemplates = db.relationship('ShiftTemplate', secondary=user_shiftTemplate, backref='employees')

class ShiftTemplate(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
    duration = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    maxEmployees = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    minEmployees = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    startTime = db.Column(db.String(4), nullable=False)
```

I have carefully made sure that the format of my ShiftTemplate table matches that of the other many-to-many relationship table I have successfully made. However, something is causing SQLAlchemy to not recognize my ShiftTemplate table for some reason. It should also be noted that in the db.ForeignKey('shifttemplate.id') line of the association table definition I have tried every capitalization combination, from shiftTemplate to ShiftTemplate to Shifttemplate and they all return the same error, so I doubt that is the cause.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I renamed my ShiftTemplate database table class to "Template" and updated all references to the table name accordingly. I have yet to discover why this works.

Answer (score 1):

`could not find table 'shifttemplate'` - Most likely name that was generated (by `flask-sqlalchemy` I presume) was a bit different from the one you used, you can manually specify tablenaem via `__tablename__` class variable, like this:

```py
class Post(Base):
    __tablename__ = "post"

    ...
```

But back to your question - yes, sqlalchemy is probably case sensitive, and not buggy :)

Comment: But if this is the case, why is it that the other many to many relationship works even though the table name specified in the association table does not exactly match the class name? For example, in my other relationship, I reference the table "shift" but the table's class name is "Shift". The capitalization plays no issue there, so why does it here? And like I said, I tried every variation of capitalization in finding the solution. It was only after I changed it to one word that it seemed to work.